# How to add a reference line to a (bar) chart in SPSS?

Tags: graph, visualization, spss, graph-visualization

Say I'm interested in knowing when a company spends too little or too much on their wages in comparison with other companies.

I made sure to make clusters. So company A only gets compared to other companies in the same cluster.
In my datasets, I added new variables. So I can easily read the aggregated mean, and based on that, an upper limit and a lower limit for each cluster.

**The problem:** But how do I visualize these?

**What I've tried:**
I can easily make bar charts or scatterplots for one cluster, where the x-axis is a selection of company ID's, and the y-axis is the mean cost of the wages. But how do I add a reference line across the chart to show the upper limit and the lower limit of one cluster? Is this not possible in SPSS?

Instead of having to do this:
[Image of bar chart where lower and upper limit are separate bars (though the same for every firm since they all belong to the same cluster)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k2FA.png)

I would like to do something like this:
[Image of bar chart where lower and upper limit are extra, horizontal reference lines across the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsDJ9.png)

Any help would be so appreciated! Just a simple confirmation that this is not possible in SPSS would also suffice. At least then I can prepare myself mentally for adding them manually in powerpoint or convince my client to use RStudio or something.

Have a lovely day!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.